# How to change point of rotation using DrawRotatedText in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, gdi

I'm using a ClientDC to draw a bunch of text, some of which needs to be rotated. I need the individual letters to each rotate around their own center, if possible, so that I can produce a line of individually rotated letters.

I know that I can use the dc.GetTextExtent() command to find the dimensions (and thus the center) of each of the letters, so that part's not too tricky. However, the command I'm using to rotate the letters, dc.DrawRotatedText(), seems to rotate around the top-left corner of each of the letters. Is it possible to change the point it treats as the center of rotation?

I'm using Windows 7, Python 2.7, wxPython Phoenix 2.8.